# What URL is the XtraUpload script posting to?

Tags: php, javascript, post, upload

I am using the XtraUpload script from http://xtrafile.com. Their forum support is very poor, and I need to write a PHP function to post to remotely post to my XtraUpload website at http://uber-upload.com.

So, I ask, ok, I *beg* for help.

Can someone please tell me what the post URL is, and what variables are being sent (i need exact names to manipulate them later)?

THANKS! I'm really stuck... =/

Note: http://uber-upload.com/js/upload.js might help...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand correctly but if you are looking to see what POST variables are being sent you can add this to your process page:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

It will output all post variables coming from the previous page

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is that you want to post your results from one site to another? I'm not sure.

Anyway, you want to check out curl connect, if you have it installed in your php build. I'm not sure exactly what you're doing, so that is the best I can give.

Otherwise, if you want to "look" at what's posted to your site, then you can use the print_r($_POST); variable as mentioned above.

Comment: What i'm trying to do is create a remote upload script that will take files from one server and post those files aswell as the variables that go with them onto http://uber-upload.com

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to debug what your page is doing, you can install firebug (for Mozilla Firefox).  It will show you all the files that are loading, and where stuff is posted to.